# How to correctly implement onBlur to dispatch API and update props in a component without creating loop on render method?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, antd, onblur

I am calling API on the onBlur/onChange of input field in Ant.Design(react redux based). on Calling API, It update the props of the component and on update of the props it call render method. in render method it re render the UI and call onBlur/onChange again and it got stuck in endless loop.

I have tried maintaining it in the state, but It is not stopping this recursive behavior.

```
render () {

const {
      form: { getFieldDecorator, getFieldValue },  payload: { payload },
    } = this.props;

 console.log(" Client details " + JSON.stringify(this.props));

return ( <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} hideRequiredMark style={{ marginTop: 8 }}>
            <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label={<FormattedMessage id="form.seller.code" />}>
              {getFieldDecorator('code', {
                rules: [
                  {
                    required: true,
                    message: formatMessage({ id: 'validation.code.required' }),
                  },
                ],
              })(<Input placeholder={formatMessage({ id: 'form.code.placeholder' })}
              onChange={this.fetchDetails()} 
               />)}
            </FormItem>
</Form>

)

}


 fetchDetails() {
    const { dispatch, form } = this.props;
    const value = this.props.form.getFieldValue('code');

dispatch({
       type: 'form/fetchDetails',
       payload: value,
     });
  }
```

expected result : just fetch the details once 
actual : repeated calls to onBlur and render method causing stuck in loop.

Comment: Try with `onChange={this.fetchDetails}` instead of `onChange={this.fetchDetails()}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `this.fetchDetails()` (call to function) to onChange, while you should pass `this.fetchDetails` (reference to function) to it.

Comment: Thankyou so much. It is working as expectedly. Can you elaborate the reason, why it was doing so??

Comment: Simply because as render gets triggered it calls fetchDetails (it is a function call, not a function reference), which in turn updates the state triggering a new render.. So that's why you got a loop